# Run a python file multiple times from Mac terminal

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal

I remember using a single line of **command in the terminal** to run a python script multiple times from the terminal and **print out the results in the terminal.** Somehow I cannot remember the exact code or find it online. It went something like:

```
python3 test.py -#number of times
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use seq and xargs and pipe to run the program x amount of times consecutively.

```
seq number_of_times_to_run | xargs -Iz python your_program.py
```

Alternatively you could use a for loop:

```
for i in {1..2}; do python your_program.py; done
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Did help! :)

Comment: Came to this solution from Google. This does not work for me as I need it to run multiple times after it's finished each time to start again. Is there another solution for this?